# Problems to implement Angular Service

Tags: angularjs

got to work with angular JS on learning how angular works.

I am trying controllers, directvies and services in an example project:

```
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpOERy][1]
```

Actually I got this error if I try to use my service on clicking the button: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '*****' of undefined

Whats my failure?

Regards n00n

Comment: @nOOn : You didn't inject the service in the controller properly. myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'CalculatorService', function ($scope, CalculatorService). Try this and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to annotate your service, little typo ;)

Your code

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, CalculatorService) {
```

Correct code

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'CalculatorService', function ($scope, CalculatorService) {
```